# How to stop redirect canonical for a single page

Tags: wordpress

The issue I'm having is similar named posts are redirecting to the wrong pages

so urls like

```
example.com/terms
```

are redirecting to

```
example.com/en/terms-of-use
```

How do I turn off wordpress's redirect_canonical only for the "terms" page?

Currently what I have

```
add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', 'disable_redirect_canonical_for_terms', 2, 10 );

function disable_redirect_canonical_for_terms( $redirect_url, $requested_url ) {
    if ( strpos( $requested_url, 'terms' ) !== false ) {
        return false;
    }
    return $redirect_url;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to turn off for all terms or particuler?

Comment: Either way, if there was a way to do it with the post id that would work

Answer (score 2):

```
/** REMOVE CANONICAL FROM SPECIFIC POST IDS **/
function sp_titles_canonical($html) {

    if( is_page( array( 3861, 4006, 4027, 4010 ) ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
      return $html;
    }

}
add_filter('seopress_titles_canonical','sp_titles_canonical');
```

Comment: Where is seopress_titles_canonical coming from?

Comment: @Tcmxc it's coming from https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-seopress/ this plugin

Answer (score 1):

You can use `is_page`. check below code.

```
add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', 'disable_redirect_canonical_for_terms', 2, 10 );
function disable_redirect_canonical_for_terms( $redirect_url, $requested_url ) {
    if( is_page( 'terms' ) ){
        return false;
    }
    return $redirect_url;
}
```

Comment: That code doesn't work.

Comment: terms are your page? or category page?

Comment: Its a page called terms. When I switch the permalinks to "Plain" the correct page is showing.

Comment: what is your current permalink structure?

Comment: The current permalink structure is /%postname%/